# Join all tables with same structure in one MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an old database already in use for years and really crappy designed.
There is a table, "Articles", which contains a "code" column that will be our PK.
And many tables like "idXXXXX" where XXXXX is a "code" value with exactly the same structure.
I looked at the application using this database and saw that relations between tables is made there.

I'm not affraid of redesign the database access in the application, but I don't want to lose years of entries in the database.

I want to create a "campain" table which will have an "id" PK and a "id_code" as FK linking "campain" to "articles"

I'm not a SQL master but I know I can get tables names with

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'id%'
```

But I have really no idea about how to deal with the result (which is fine).
So how can I access to every tables named "idXXX" and insert every rows in the "campain" table + set "id_code" column to "XXX"?

---

Here is the procedure I saved (I didn't add every fields in the INSERT line for testing purpose) :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE JoinAllTables()
BEGIN

 DECLARE done INT default 0;
 DECLARE tableName CHAR(9); 
 DECLARE buffStr CHAR(7);
 DECLARE buffId INT default 0;

 DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'id%'; 
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;


 OPEN cur1;

 read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO tableName;
    IF done THEN
       LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

  SET buffStr = SUBSTRING(tableName, 3);
  SET buffId = CAST(buffStr AS SIGNED);

  set @sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO campagnes(id, id_code) SELECT null, bufId FROM ",tableName); # Dynamically building sql statement 
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

As u can see, I sub 'idXXXXX' to 'XXXXX' then CAST it AS INTEGER (SIGNED).
But I guess that in the "INSERT INTO" line, second tableName doesn't point to the variable. That's why I'm getting a 
"#1446 - Tabble 'bddsoufflage.tablename'doesn't exist" Error :) Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: Updated answer**

We can't have the tableName dynamically changed inside a prepared statement, so we must go through DynamicSQL to build the query using CONCAT, then compile the SQL with PREPARE, EXECUTE it and DEALLOCATE it.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE JoinAllTables()
BEGIN

 DECLARE done INT default 0;
 DECLARE tableName CHAR(9); 
 DECLARE buffStr CHAR(7);
 DECLARE buffId INT default 0;

 DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'id%'; 
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

 OPEN cur1;

 read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO tableName;
    IF done THEN
       LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

  SET buffStr = SUBSTRING(tableName, 3);
  SET buffId = CAST(buffStr AS SIGNED);

  set @sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO campagnes(id, id_code) SELECT null, ", buffId, " FROM ",tableName); # Dynamically building sql statement 
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur1;
END; //
```

See also this answer [MySQL Pass table name to cursor select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931287/mysql-pass-table-name-to-cursor-select)

**Old answer**
The procedure should look something like this. Thanks Mchl for providing an Insert Into query example, I simply added it to the rest of the procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE JoinAllTables()
BEGIN

 DECLARE done INT default 0;
 DECLARE tableName CHAR(7); # Variable to contain table names CHAr(7) is assuming id + 5Xs as characters.

 DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'id%'; # Create a cursor to iterate over the tables
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

 OPEN cur1;

 read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO tableName;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    #Your Insert statement here, using tableName as a field.
INSERT INTO campain (id, id_code, otherfields) SELECT null, tableName, otherfields FROM tableName;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur1;
END;//
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot, I'll try that, but in MYSQL, I don't think I can use a field like "idXXXX" as PK, maybe should I remove "id" part and convert "XXXX" to INT ?

Comment: Yes, you might want to reprocess the tableName to something else, using SUBSTRING() function to extract the XXXs and then converting that into a number using CAST() function.

Comment: I'm getting an Error at line 4 =/ ( DECLARE tableName CHAR(7); ) talking about syntax error near '' That's quite weird because I tried to remove the whole line (in case of bad copy/paste) and it changed nothing.

Comment: Yeah sorry, In my rush to add the comment before leaving, I omitted the DELIMITER // to make MySQL accept the procedure on the mysql> prompt. Also I had forgotten to declare the done variable.
You still have to probably adjust the CURSOR SELECT query and the INSERT query to your specific tables in the DB.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll take a look at that later today.

Comment: Hi, After some modifications, I've been able to execute your procedure. But I think you made a mistake somewhere ^^. When I CALL the procedure, I get this Error : "MYDATABASENAME".tableName doesn't exist. I guess it's line "FETCH cur1 INTO tableName" or  "INSERT INTO" one which is concerned.

Comment: I added my (your) code as a new answer because of characters limitations in comments ;)

Comment: You made another mistake. buffId is a variable, you can't use it in the INSERT INTO like that. (+You should edit, You typed bufId, my variable is with 2 f)

Comment: Then I need to extend the CONCAT again... :P Sorry it's such a step process ^^

Comment: It's OK, I already corrected this and it worked :D I also added all fields... I'll edit my bot answer just to show you why I didn't wrote them before (but i'm quite sure u saw worst). Anyway Thanks again I'll set this thread as SOLVED ;)
Edit : I can't edit my own answer ? Nevermind Thx again You saved me a lot of time and teached me a lot !

Comment: Great! Happy to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to run the information_schema query you have within some script (PHP,Python,Perl - whichever suits you best) and use it's results to create queries like:

```
INSERT INTO 
  campain (id, id_code, otherfields)
SELECT
  null, 'idXXXX', otherfields FROM idXXXX
```

Comment: Hum I'll try that, but isn't there a way to do it in pure SQL ?

Comment: There is, see @NetSquirell's answer ;) I just don't like writign stored procs like that ;P