# How to run mysql queries that are stored in a mysql table using a procedure

Tags: mysql

I am developing a simple WPF(C#) application where i am storing all insert, update and delete queries in a table. These queries are then executed on server one by one by simply selecting and then executing using ExecuteNonQuery() function in c#. The problem is that if have a large number of queries then it becomes very slow and sometimes due to network connection it is falling out.
Is it possible to create a stored procedure that can execute the queries stored within a table on the same server?

Here is some code that I have tried till now.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `MyProc`(wo varchar(100))
BEGIN
              DECLARE x  INT;
              DECLARE str  text;
              set x = 0;
              select count(*) into x from tblqueries where isexecutedonserver  = false and woid = wo;
              SET str =  '';
              REPEAT
                          select `query` into str from tblqueries where id = 2976;
                          SET  x = x - 1;
              UNTIL x  > 0
              END REPEAT;
              ##select str;
              prepare stmt from @str;
              execute stmt;
              deallocate prepare stmt;
      END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Sometimes it work well, but as you can see if the application is used by number of clients with a single server then it will have great number of server requests which is not good in my point of view. Thanks

Comment: Hi Vulkanino, Still trying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple (as simple as googling "mysql stored procedure execute")

Declare a `CURSOR` in your stored procedure.
Execute the cursor, then prepare a statement with the output:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @myvar;
```

This code will help you with it:
[MySQL Pass table name to cursor select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931287/mysql-pass-table-name-to-cursor-select)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is a view.

Views (including updatable views) are available in MySQL Server 5.0. Views are stored queries that when invoked produce a result set. A view acts as a virtual table. Views are available in binary releases from 5.0.1 and up.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html

Comment: Hi Paul, I am not agree with you as view has no relation with query execution.

Comment: a view IS a query. Please read my link and if you still disagree, read it again. ;)

Comment: this is not what he asked Paul.